# Wicket Quickstart on Tomcat: Servlet NoSuchMethodError

Tags: tomcat, wicket

New to Wicket and Java web development. I got a quickstart project from the Wicket website, and I'm trying to run it on a local Tomcat server. The homepage is currently giving me a error: "javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception".

Here's the stack trace:

```
Oct 05, 2015 10:40:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.isAsyncStarted()Z
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.ServletWebResponse.flush(ServletWebResponse.java:319)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.HeaderBufferingWebResponse.flush(HeaderBufferingWebResponse.java:99)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:263)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've added the tomcat 8 library and its servlet-api.jar to my classpath. There doesn't seem to be anything about servlets in pom.xml or web.xml. I've read that it might be a servlet-api version issue, but mvn install seems to be installing the right version (3.1.0). Here's the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
(the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.drat.proteus</groupId>
<artifactId>proteus</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <!-- TODO project name  -->
<name>quickstart</name>
<description></description>
<!--
    <organization>
        <name>company name</name>
        <url>company url</url>
    </organization>
-->
<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
</licenses>
<properties>
    <wicket.version>7.0.0</wicket.version>
    <jetty9.version>9.2.11.v20150529</jetty9.version>
    <log4j.version>2.3</log4j.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!-- allowed values: R7, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0 or none -->
    <wtp.version>none</wtp.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!--  WICKET DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    -->

    <!-- LOGGING DEPENDENCIES - LOG4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  JUNIT DEPENDENCY FOR TESTING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--  JETTY DEPENDENCIES FOR TESTING  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty9.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty9.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty9.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-jmx</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty9.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty9.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <name>maven.project.build.directory.test-classes</name>
                        <value>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                </systemProperties>
                <jettyXml>${project.basedir}/src/test/jetty/jetty.xml,${project.basedir}/src/test/jetty/jetty-ssl.xml,${project.basedir}/src/test/jetty/jetty-http.xml,${project.basedir}/src/test/jetty/jetty-https.xml</jettyXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <wtpversion>${wtp.version}</wtpversion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Apache Nexus</id>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
</project>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The method isAsyncStarted exists since servlet-api 3.0, see https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#isAsyncStarted%28%29 which servlet API do you use?

Comment: @MartinStrejc When I do a mvn install, all instances of servlet-api are 3.1.0 but, like I said, nothing in the pom.xml mentions a servlet so I'm not really sure where that's coming from. I've added the pom file to my post.

Comment: The maven dependency in POM has scope 'provided'. That means it is accessible from the code, it's compiled with that library, but it is not a part of the final war. The reason is that the JAR library is expected to be a part of the server (e.g. Tomcat) in a shared directory (e.g. libs). See https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

Change the version in the web.xml to 3.0, now it is still on 2.5

from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
      version="2.5">
...
</web-app>
```

to:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0">
...
</web-app>
```

or:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
...
</web-app>
```

Maybe this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I've fixed Wicket's quickstart Maven archetype.

Comment: Did this and it didn't solve the servlet issue. Definitely good to have done though.